# Converting time into UTC

Tags: php

I know this question has been asked before but somehow I am not able to get this to work in my project so please advise

my php code ( this if else is for checking if time was set or not )

```
if (isset($_POST['startDate']) && isset($_POST['startTime']))
{
    $date = $_POST['startDate'] . " " . $_POST['startTime'];
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
//    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

} else
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
}
```

Comment: `not able to get this to work` So we just get to guess what happens? And what values you're using?

Comment: What about it is not working? For your else, you don't need to pass a date into DateTime. If you don't pass anything in, it will use the current time.

Comment: `echo $_POST['startDate'] . " " . $_POST['startTime'];`  What is it?

Comment: $datetime = "2016-02-01 00:00:01";
$given = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 
$given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$output = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
echo ($output);

Comment: Try This... ......

Comment: " $datetime " is your $date variable ... where you get the value from the input fields ..

Comment: I am getting the values in input type date and time as 2 separate fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This::**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>   

    <form action="#" method="POST">

        <input name="startDate" type="date"/>

      <br>

        <input name="startTime" type="time"/>

        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

if(isset($_POST['startDate']) && isset($_POST['startTime']))
{
    $date = $_POST['startDate'] . " " . $_POST['startTime'];
    // $date = "2016-02-01 00:00:01"; Like This..
    
    $date  = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    $date ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
  
  $output = $date ->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
  //echo $output;

 $date = new DateTime($output); 

//    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

} else
{
    $date ->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
    $date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    $date ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
}


}


?>
```

Comment: I Try This .. Its Work For Me !! :)

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');    .. You Can Set Your Default Time Zone if You Get Wrong Time  ..

Comment: @dhaval .. you try this .. locally to run this code.   What output you get ??

Comment: I found the solution .. I had to convert $Output back to DateTime object and now it working..please edit the code and I will mark your code as correct

Comment: yes.. this will be the last line to convert the UTC datetime into DateTime Object

Comment: Okk its work...so then I updated my answer :) thank u